# nextprops condtion not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am very much familiar with the react and react-redux. I have one evergreen condition which almost I have been using to my every project.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.apps !== this.props.apps) {
    this.apiCall()
  }
}
```

Here `apps` contain arrays of objects. But switching from one route to another route a place exists where this condition fails even both the `nextProps.apps` and `this.props.apps` are same. I don't know why this is happening. I have used it many times.

**React version -> 16.x**

Comment: you cannot compare arrays with `===`. You have to check the contents of the array to see if they match

Comment: @azium Its array of objects. not just array of elements.

Comment: whatever it is, you probably want to be doing a deep comparison. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual

Comment: go with what @azium suggested

Comment: Not totally accurate. I think if you make sure to never mutate your state, a shallow comparison should be enough because then all thats needed is a referential check. If you need a shallow comparison, there is a good chance you are mutating state. Something to think about.

Comment: meant to say if you need a DEEP comparison.

Comment: @azium Ok I will check tomorrow. Is there any better way of doing the same?

Comment: @ChaimFriedman Do you have any better way to do the same?